# Unit Testing without a main static method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am starting to go through a tutorial on Unit Testing. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I am trying to run the projects/ tests but keep getting these errors,

CS5001  Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

CS006   Metadata file 'C:(filepath)... .exe' could not be found

I know neither class has a main static method but the tutorial I am following along with doesn't either so I am not sure what the issue is. I have searched Stack Overflow and Google but can only find answers going over my head, any idea what how to fix this?

It is pretty simple code as I am just at the beginning so I think the problem is something else but am not sure (obviously)

UPDATE:
Here is a screen shot of the structure of my solution:
[structure of solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRlrK.png)
The original project was a Console application, the I added a Test project to the solution.

Comment: Sounds like you used a console app template when you created your project, you should create a Unit Test project instead

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test project are not applications and are normally run using a test runner.

Run you tests from VS's Test Explorer

[image]

[image]

Option B. Run the test directly from its code.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to run the tests like a regular application (Ctrl+F5). Didn't realize they "run" differently with 'Ctrl+A+R'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've written your unit tests inside a Console Application template, removed the Program class's `Main()` method and hit F5 to run your unit tests.

You don't F5 unit tests, you run them from a test runner. Right-click any of your test methods and choose something like "Run Unit Tests" to show that test runner. Or click Test -> Test Explorer to see all discovered tests. See also [Run unit tests in "Get started with unit testing"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2019&tabs=mstest#run-unit-tests).

If that works, create a new project that's actually a Unit Test Project so you at least get a fancy project icon, and move your test code into that project.

Comment: The original solution is a console project, but for the tests I created another test project. Is that correct?

Comment: In that case you probably removed something from your Program class that you shouldn't have removed.

Comment: You cannot run it the same way. F5 is for normal applications, for tests you need to open the test explorer and run them there (or Ctrl-R-Ctrl-T on the test class or test method).

Comment: You could place your tests into a class library. VS can execute the tests in from the dll if you for example have installed nUnit 3 Test Adapter as extension.